# React native application release build install on Simulator but not on device

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, development-environment

I have done all provisioning profile setup on excode with manual Provisiong profile and my build is succeeded on xcode also running on simulator with release build but when I create ipa file and its not installing on device almost on 75% its stops and nothing happen.

My Xcode version is 9.2 with iOS 11.2 I'm installing on iOS 12.1.2 iphone device. Is anything I'm doing wrong?

https://www.raywenderlich.com/120-how-to-submit-an-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

For provisioning profile and generate certificates + add App ID with UDID I have done exact procedure.

Comment: What kind of distribution provisioning profile are you using `ad-hoc` or `release`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're signing your ipa file using an AppStore certificate, you can't install it directly on your iPhone without passing through Apple's review or AppStore first. So, maybe there's two solutions for your problem:

- Build your app as Release and sign with a Development certificate; or
- Sign your release app with an Ad-Hoc certificate;

Furthermore, Ad-Hoc certificates enable you to install your live app directly into a limited number of devices without passing through AppStore. I think that's what you want.

See more on [Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html).

And there's also this [link](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile).

Comment: Thanks brother its helped me to build for release :-)